# How to make an interruption?

Tags: microcontroller, c, arm

I used to make interruptions on a STM32 the next way

```
#include "stm32f407xx.h"

#define USART3_IRQ_NUM 39

void USART3_IRQHandler(void)
{
    while(1);
}

int main (void)
{
    NVIC_Type *pNVIC= NVIC //Enable the USART3 interrupt 
    pNVIC->ISER[1] = pNVIC->ISER[1] | (1<<(39-32));

    //Pending the interruption
    pNVIC->ISPR[1] = pNVIC->ISPR[1] | (1<<(39-32));

    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Im trying to do with a tm4c1294nctpd, I understand that both cards make use of the same ARM M4, so all it would take is to update the USART3_IRQ_NUM?.
Looking for the ISER and ISPR but I cant find it in the documentation of the tm4c.

Besides the include directive fails to locate the tm4c1294nctpd.h, it is supposed to be instaled alongside the code composer studio.

Comment: Why did you put an endless loop in your ISR?

Comment: STM32 and TM4C even though they are both Cortex-M chips it is only the CPU and NVIC (interrupt controller) that are the same. The peripherals that generate the interrupts are different, so you need to find out in the reference manuals how to enable them. Also try to use CMSIS functions like NVIC_EnableIRQn().

Comment: @Mike to create a MCVE?

Comment: TI has provided a wealth of information about this micro controller. They have a product called TivaWare (software). Within that there is an example project called "Interrupts" (along with a ton of other examples). I would recommending downloading TivaWare and studying the example(s).